# Interface Builder - Constraint maximum width and margins

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints

I have a constraint error,

What I want to do is "center the view, have 20 margin on the view, and have a maximum width of 320"

So that on iPad the view is not stretched, but on smaller devices the view can be less than 320 width, and have 20 pts of margin.

However using these rules gives me an error, probably because I say that margins can be >= 20, and width <= 320, and view has no idea how to match that.

I tried using priority but I'm not sure how it works, and I couldn't get anything.

How can I achieve the desired effect using only one view and its constraints?

[image]

Comment: Change the leading/trailing constraints to = 20 and set their priority to 999 so they can be broken on wider devices

Comment: You have already said "center it horizontally" so there is no need for both a leading and a trailing constraint.

Comment: @Paulw11 cool, that makes the trick! Post it as answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @matt Yes however I want it horizontally aligned, but with a margin. Or is there a constraint like "stretch to parent but with margin" ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you have deduced, autolayout needs to know which constraint it should break in the event of a conflict, and this is done by priorities. However, you have another conflict since the leading/trailing and width constraints are all relative. This means that autolayout cannot determine the view's width.

Change the leading/trailing constraints to = 20 and set their priority to 999 so they can be broken on a wider device. This will allow the width to be determined and eliminate your conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

Note that (1) we don't need a trailing margin constraint, as we are already horizontally centered, and (2) the width of 320 has a lowered priority, thus giving the inequality leading margin constraint something to aim at when in doubt but otherwise not interfering.

This is what it looks like on iPhone 4s in Portrait: we are restrained by the side margins:

[image]

This is what it looks like on an iPhone 4s in Landscape (and of course on anything wider than that): we expand our width, but only up to 320:

[image]

Comment: Note that `leadingMargin` is not flush with the left edge of the superview. If htafoya wants exactly 20 points of margin, that constraint will need to change to just use `leading`.

Comment: @robmayoff Agreed. I couldn't quite figure out what he meant about the margin. In his screen shot, he is pinned to the superview's margin, not to its edge. But I cannot tell whether he realizes what that ultimately means. So the point of my answer is to illustrate the needed _concepts_, but of course juggling the exact numbers is up to the OP.

Comment: Uhm, I placed the same constraints that you had but the margin was always 20, so when I expanded to iPad the view exanded to fill all but 20 pts on each side. Paulw11 gives the constraints I am looking for.

Comment: And sorry for my definitions, I am talking about Margin because that's the concept in Android layouts and I believe it's the same for CSS.

Comment: @htafoya I've no problem with your accepting Paulw11's answer; he was first, and in any case it's your right. But you are wrong that my solution doesn't work. If it didn't work for you, then you didn't do what I said. I can send you a working example if you like. Basically Paulw11's answer and mine are completely equivalent; to resolve the conflict, it's just a matter of make one constraint or the other an equality at reduced property. He picked one, I picked the other. If you don't understand that, you have not understood either solution.

Comment: @matt I understand it, but somehow it didn't work (and as we know sometimes common logic doesn't apply to these kind of tools). I will try later, maybe I missed something. I have not much time so as you said, the first solution that worked was good for me :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. Glad you solved it. I'm the same way!